# Android: TextView property "textAllCaps" causes XML Inflate error when fontFamily is set to sans-serif-condensed

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

This is an interesting error, and I've been able to reproduce it consistently. I wonder if anyone else has noticed it; I haven't been able to find any reports on it.

The TextView widget has a property called `textAllCaps` that is used to force any text displayed in it to be in all caps. This property has been in Android since API level 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich). However, I discovered recently that if you set the Font Family for your app to sans-serif-condensed by putting this in styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
```

Then when any layout is inflated that has a TextView with `textAllCaps=true`, then it crashes with an `InflateException`:

```
12-05 09:18:48.847 16727 16727 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class TextView
12-05 09:18:48.847 16727 16727 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class TextView
12-05 09:18:48.847 16727 16727 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=57; index=2491
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: did you try to put it in font foler like this  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sans-serif-condensed</item>

Comment: That gives me a "Resource not found" error on compile.

Comment: rename the font. a call  directily form xml android:fontFamily="@font/sans_serif_condensed". Just let me knw

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this, and setting the TextView style property to the app theme style prevents crashes for me.

Example:

```
<style names="MyAppTheme">
   <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

then:

```
<TextView
        style="@style/MyAppTheme"
        ...
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

**Edit for additional info:**

After looking at this further my best guess is the bug lies in the TextView code. The original crash is an indexOutOfBoundsException, which in the question shows this:

```
length=57; index=2491
```

I think the 57 element list is the style information available to the TextView, and the 2491+ element list is the style information applied to the TextView including the AppTheme information. The style item at position 2491 is likely required for the `textAllCaps` property to be applied. The issue is likely the TextView isn't made aware of the extra style information unless set explicitly, hence why the above fix circumvents the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This a know bug and can be tracked here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64053344 .

Here is a quick workaround for you. Change you code

From :

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="android:...">
  <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
</style>
```

To this :

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="android:...">
   <item name="fontFamily">@string/default_font</item>
</style>
```

And define default_font in `strings.xml` file.